# Why does xcode archive succeed but create an empty .xcarchive file?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, app-store

**Background**

I have an application I'm trying to archive and submit to the app store for approval. Part of the process requires the archive to be prepared and loaded using application loader. I used product-> archive and it prompts archive succeeded but it does not appear on the Organizer -> Archive tab.

**Detail of Project build**

1 app target, "AppName"

1 static library, cocos2d libraries (cocos2d v0.99.5-rc1)

Xcode Version 4.0.2

**First steps**

Setting "Skip Install" to "No":

1. Project
2. AppName target
3. cocos2d libraries

Setting skip install on the three allows me the archive to be built and show up(non-empty xcarchive) on the organizer. However, when I try to validate, it'll prompt:

"AppName" does not contain a single–bundle application or contains multiple products. Please select another archive, or adjust your scheme to create a single–bundle application.

I checked that the archive package contents include the cocos2d libraries within a directory "Products". According to some posts and the cocos2d forum, we're not supposed to submit that as part of the binary for approval.

**Steps taken to the Zero KB .xcarchive**

Since the static cocos2d libraries library should not to be included, I've changed the cocos2d libraries target to have skip install: "Yes". Now, if I archive the project it prompts build succeeded but it creates an empty .xcarchive file that cannot be seen on the organizer->archives tab.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have the solution to my problem and if anyone else is facing the same problem here are the steps i took to fix the problem.

cocos2d library

-Set the skip install to YES for all configurations in your cocos2d library.

-Set the code signing identity to Don't code sign for all configurations. Static libraries are not code signed.

-Update the installation directory to /usr/local/lib.

app library

-Update the installation build products location to /tmp/$(PROJECT_NAME).dst

-Update the installation directory to $(LOCAL_APPS_DIR) (/Applications).

-Update the code signing identity section.

Comment: This saved me a lot of time today after 4-5 years of adding answer. I am working on xcode 7.1

Answer (score 8):

What worked for me was to delete the lines `SKIP_INSTALL = YES;` from the various *.pbxproj files.

Hat tip to [this blog](https://www.dzhang.com/blog/2011/03/11/xcode-4-succeeded-archiving-app-but-nothing-appears-in-organizer). (No instances of `INSTALL_PATH` found in our files.)

Comment: Thanks! Simply setting "Skip Install" to NO (by deleting the override to YES) fixed the empty archive for me as well.