# Xcode 4 archive not showing up in Organizer

Tags: iphone, xcode, archive, organizer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Archives not showing up in Organizer for XCode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265772/archives-not-showing-up-in-organizer-for-xcode-4)

When I go to archive my app, everything builds without error, but the archive doesnt show up in the Organizer, and the .xcarchive file is 0 bytes.

I've looked at solutions all over the web and on here, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280914/archive-does-not-appear-in-xcode4-organizer), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6716756/why-does-xcode-archive-succeed-but-create-an-empty-xcarchive-file),  [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722414/cant-archive-anymore-yet-build-for-archive-still-works-xcode-4), setting 'Skip Install' flags to YES/NO in all areas for all build types, cleaning, deleting/readding my Entitlements.plist file, with NO LUCK.

Does anyone know of anything else I can try?

Comment: Just a sanity check suggestion - if you click "Share" in the organizer can you save an .ipa file at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up re-creating project, could not find a way to solve this issue otherwise.

Answer (score 7):

Verify that the 'Installation Directory' is set for your application target.  Installation seems to be skipped if this is left empty, regardless of the 'Skip Install' flag.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using the menu item, "Product" -> "Build For" -> "Build for Archiving"? I was doing that the first time I tried to make an Archive, but it doesn't create it. Using just "Product" -> "Archive" did the job for me.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that fixed this for me was re-installing XCode.